# Command Line Graphviz PHP bug

Tags: php, command-line, graphviz

when i try to execute this through php it doesn't work but the same works like charm when i execute directly on command line!

$HOME/local/bin/dot -Tgif -o $HOME/public_html/ERG/test.png $HOME/public_html/ERG/test.txt

any help will be appreciated

For PHP i am using following

Comment: not luck yet! don't know how to debug it!